# how to load template for add or edit record in for syncfusion grid in partial view

Tags: angularjs, syncfusion

I have to do when  for edit and add record in grid  i have to load adding record template in partial view in place of grid view

i. e. in place of grid view i have to load add record template and dont want to show grid and after save click on template i have to load that grid with added new record
please suggest solution only using AngularJS

```
<div ng-controller="LeadListController">
<div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-lg-9 col-md-9">
    <div id="Grid" ej-grid e-datasource="data" e-allowgrouping="true" e-pagesettings-pagesize="8" e-pagesettings-currentpage="page" e-toolbarsettings-showtoolbar='true' e-toolbarsettings-toolbaritems='tools' e-editsettings-allowdeleting=' true'
        e-editsettings-allowediting='true' e-editsettings-allowadding='true' e-allowpaging="true" e-beginedit="disableedit" e-sortsettings="sorting"
        e-editsettings-editmode='externalform' e-formposition="bottomLeft" e-editsettings-inlineformtemplateid="#template" e-selectedrowindex="selectedRow" e-allowsorting="true" e-endedit="endedit" e-actionbegin="actionBegin" e-actioncomplete="complete">
        <div e-columns>
            <div e-column e-field="EmployeeID" e-headertext="Employee ID" e-textalign="right" e-width="90"></div>
            <div e-column e-field="LastName" e-headertext="Last Name" e-textalign="left" e-width="90"></div>
            <div e-column e-field="FirstName" e-headertext="FirstName" e-textalign="left" e-width="90"></div>
            <div e-column e-field="Title" e-headertext="Title" e-textalign="left" e-width="90"></div>
            <div e-column e-field="City" e-headertext="City" e-textalign="left" e-width="90"></div>
            <div e-column e-field="Country" e-headertext="Country" e-textalign="left" e-width="90"></div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you have routed the view on editing, then you have to handle the edit operation by user self and the grid will not handle it. is it okay for you?

Comment: I have not used routing because i dont have to show url in browser addressbar. I have used ng-hide to hide grid and to handle the edit operation by user self i have show another  page in place of grid 

but problem is that when i have back from that edit view then i have to show grid but doesnt work becoz it goes in child controller for edit operation

Comment: If possible make a fiddle to show us your problem. http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: like $scope.back = function () {
        alert($scope.$parent.gridpage);
        alert($scope.$parent.leadview);


         $scope.$parent.leadview = false;
        $scope.$parent.gridpage = true;
     
    };

Comment: i have uploaded code on following link::http://jsfiddle.net/gomteshhatgine/9v4r8opd/

Comment: above problem solved by giving single controller for both views

Comment: but when i click on add or edit butoon button is disabled for add form but when i load grid page it will show disabled button for add and edit in grid how to enable that buttons

Comment: for this click ::  $scope.back = function () {
      
        $scope.leadview = false;

        $scope.gridpage = true;

//here i have eenabel that buttons

    };

Comment: To enable button use the actionBegin event to open the edit template dont use actionComplete and use `args.cancel = true` at the end of function. `<div id="Grid" e-actionbegin="complete"/>` and function definition `$scope.complete = function (args) {
        if (args.requestType == "add") {

            $scope.gridpage = false;

            $scope.leadview = true;

            $route.reload(); args.cancel = true;
        }
}`

Comment: I am still working on to find why child scope not worked, i will let u know once found solution.

Comment: Please mark it as anwser if its helpful...

Answer (score 0):

The `ng-if` create new child scope like `ng-include` and hence access `$scope.$parent.gridpage` inside the child controller will search for the `gridpage` inside the scope created by `ng-if` and hence its not working.

And so to access the controller scope of the grid, use as follows.

```
 $scope.back = function () {        
     $scope.$parent.$parent.leadview = false;
     $scope.$parent.$parent.gridpage = true;
     . . . . .

};
```